# How can I check which property of the entity is modified before SaveChanges?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using the EF with asp.net mvc5. I want the property which is modified while the update/edit entity. 
I can get it using the `context.Entry(blog).Property("Name").IsModified = true;` but for this I have to check each property for this entity.
Is there any way I can get the direct property name and updated value?

Comment: May I ask why do you need it?

Comment: I want it to make a partial commit in the solr. Right now we need to index full entity. To reduce the effort of indexing again and again full entity.

Comment: Interesting idea. But is it really such a problem? We have very similar case and we just index whole entry again each time and don't have any problems.

Comment: Yes but in our case we have millions of entity to be updated so its better to make a partial commit instead of full index in solr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the property names that have changed:

```
var entry = context.Entry(myEntity);
var changedProperties = entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames
    .Where(p => entry.Property(p).IsModified);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this gives me all properties not only updated !! I need only updated one.

Comment: With the Where clause (the last line) it should only return updated values. Did you include the last line?

Comment: Yes it should return updated values but its not giving updated value. It is returning all property.